# How to use diffrent text_style in a textline in multi lingual App

Tags: flutter

For example I want to have this text_line in a page:

Your session ended because there was **no activity** for a long time.

that **no activity** is bold.
I know ,I can use RichText for a single language app.
and my problem is what i should do for making the app multi language,where I use intl and flutter_localizations packages.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Use Text.rich as following:

```
Text.rich(TextSpan(
                  text: 'Your session ended because there was ',
                  children: [
                    TextSpan(
                      text: 'no activity',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,),
                    ),
                    TextSpan(
                      text: 'for a long time',
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            )
```